# Postman-Jenkins-Jira Integration

Tags: jira-xray, postman-newman

I have a postman collection which in turn is integrated to Jenkins via newman.
I need to integrate my Jenkin results with Jira via X-ray plugin.
I tried using newman junitxray reporter but this report consider each request as test case.
In my collection i always need to run some series of request before running the actual request which contain pm.test.
But junitxray report is considering those series of request as also test cases.
I want only a specific request to be taken as test-case.
Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Hi Shruti, has my answer helped you out? If so, can I kindly ask you to mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different reporters with newman; depending on that, what will be on the JUnit XML report will be different. Some time ago I've prepared a tutorial showing the differences.

If you're using Xray on Jira cloud, please check [this tutorial and related code](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Developing+and+testing+APIs+using+Postman).

If you're using Xray on Jira server/datacenter, please check [this tutorial and related code instead](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Developing+and+testing+APIs+using+Postman).